# MakerBot won't slice my model

Tags: 3d-printing, optimization

I need to make a casing for an Arduino device. Since I am new to Blender I am struggling a bit but I successfully managed to make a casing with a lid.

I also did some cleanup to prepare for 3D printing (I followed some Youtube tutorials).

But now when I export my model to `.stl` and try to slice it with Makerbot, I get an error

> messages.build.error.SliceException

What am I missing? I would be happy for any help

Here are some pictures an here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pspotopopi91qy5/Casing.blend?dl=0

[image: Pic1]
[image: Pic2]

### EDIT:

After supporting all orphaned vertices (thank you bertmoog for your answer) I could successfully slice the model. Now I have a problem, that MakerBot doesn't seem to slice all sides equally, though they are the same thickness.

It looks like this:

[image: Pic2]

Should I thicken this side, or is there any less "hacky" solution?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange. When you are including a .blend file in your question or answer, please use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). This is a site set up by one of our members and .blends stay on it forever, rather than being deleted after a set amount of time. This means that people can still learn from your question years later, without having to ask for clarification, making it easier for everybody. Thank you, and happy Blending!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have (what looks to be) several orphaned edges in the model that I found by selecting all vertices in ***Vertex*** select mode, then switching to ***Face*** selection.  I can't say if this is what's causing the error because I don't have MakerBot, but I've removed the edges which serve no purpose.

[image]

***EDIT (from your comment):*** With faces it's a little more complicated than just drawing an edge from point to point, especially when exporting to a different format/program.  The face needs to be planar (existing in a single plane) and no geometry should exist that doesn't support at least one particular face.  In your case, there were multiple ***2D*** edges (in other words, they can't exist in real space... matter always exists in 3D) that I'm guessing Makerbot couldn't resolve because they weren't adding to the box's substance.

***For the addition you made to the question***, it looks like MakerBot isn't recognizing a face on the outside.  It also looks like it's missing the faces on the rim.  I deleted those faces, added two corner edges for more geometry, and then re-faced the rim and side.

Please try it and let me know, hopefully it will help.  If not, it's difficult to say what's going on:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seemed to work! So If I understand correctly, vertexes should have at least 3 connected edges for better integrity?
I sliced the model, it all fine but one side appeares to be thinner. Please see original question.

Comment: @tomiG - See edit to answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!. Even though the result appears to be the same you gave me insights on what to watch out for and I will experiment with the object untill I get the desired results.

Comment: @tomiG - I'm sorry about that.  That's really odd that it won't recognize those faces, I can't say why.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer (since your original question was solved) so it will go out of the unanswered questions list.  I would recommend asking a new question to deal with the absent geometry after slicing.  Maybe somebody else will be able to help.